# Ruby doesn't believe any external files exist and i don't know why?

Tags: ruby

I've been learning ruby through this YouTube tutorial
https://youtu.be/t_ispmWmdjY

So far it's been going well until I got to the section about reading or writing files,
for whatever reason the external file which I named "demons.txt" does not work and when I tried to run the code

```
File.open("demons.txt", "r")
```

I get this error

Ruby/practice2.rb:1:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - demons.txt (Errno::ENOENT)

I started to suspect it was because ruby couldn't find the file and sure enough when I ran

```
puts File.exist?("demons.txt")
```

I am given a "false" which makes absolutely no sense to me since I can clearly see the file I'm trying to read in the explorer within the same directory with the exact same name and it's starting to infuriate me that I can't even think of a possible solution, help!

Comment: are you sure the upper/lower casing is correct?

Comment: @Foo L Positive, spelling and casing was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Quick update, it seems to have no trouble finding the file by representing the absolute path. However I still think it should work with just the relative, in this case being "demons.txt" any further insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [`Dir.pwd`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Dir.html#pwd-method) to see what directory you're currently in. There's also `Dir.entries('.')` to get a list of filenames in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a Ruby program, it will have a current directory.  Make sure that the current directory when you execute the program is the directory that contains the file.  For example:

```
cd ~/myproject/data    # Assuming this dir contains demons.txt
~/myproject/bin/myprogram
```

For additional debugging, include these lines (assuming Linux):

```
system("pwd")
system("ls -l demons.txt")
```

The first will show you what the currently directory is.  The second will show you the directory entry for the file you are trying to open.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm an idiot, I was running the program within the root directory. Works perfectly now that I've gone down the hierarchy into the appropriate folder.

Comment: @Kuzunoha I'm glad you got it working!  You're not an idiot, it's just a mistake to learn from.  All programmers make them.  Lots of them.